# What is a "best case scenario" to use predicate(java.util.function.Predicate) in java

Tags: java, java-8

I am going through the code which uses Predicate in Java 8.Can someone help me with the best case scenario to use Predicate. In Which cases we should use Predicate and in which scenarios if conditions is used?

Comment: What is a "best case scenario"?

Answer (score 5):

You use a `Predicate` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)) when you need a function that takes one argument and returns a `boolean`.

For example, you can use a `Predicate` in a situation where you want to filter a stream to remove elements that don't satisfy some logical condition, or find the first element that satisfies the  condition.

If you want more examples, look at the [interface usage javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/class-use/Predicate.html) for the `Predicate` interface.  It lists all of the Java SE methods that take a `Predicate` instance as an argument or return one as their result.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html

This is a functional interface that represents a function from something to bool. Java does not have function types or unrestricted first-class functions, but it does have interfaces that represent particular subtypes of functions.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

> Functional interfaces provide target types for lambda expressions and
>   method references.

Here's an example of a predicate that returns `true` if the length of a string is greater than 5.

```
Predicate<String> i = (s) -> s.length(5) > 5;
```

Any method taking a `Predicate` as an argument supports the lambda syntax, since that is one of the concrete types that can be inferred for a lambda expression.

A `Predicate` is a distinct thing from a general `Function` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) because a `Function` cannot return a primitive type.